# Cakephp 2.0 and basic auth

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've upgraded my app from CakePHP 1.3 to 2.0.4.

Previously, I was able to use the Security component to emulate Basic HTTP authentication only in one controller.

I used to do something like this:

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('*'));
$this->Security->loginOptions = array('type'=>'basic','realm'=>'api');
$this->Security->loginUsers = array("api"=>"123");
$this->Security->requireLogin();
```

Now SecurityComponent no longer handles Basic and Digest Authentication and I need to do something like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('Basic')
    )
);
```

But when I use this on my ApiController it redirects to my login form at /users/login. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the AuthComponent with your login action. You should check out the section on [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html?#configuring-authentication-handlers) in the Cake book.

Your setup will probably look something similar to this:

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth'=> array(
    'loginAction' => array(
      'controller' => 'api',
      'action'     => 'login'
    ),
    'loginRedirect' => array(
      'controller' => 'api',
      'action'     => 'logged_on'
    ),
    'authenticate' => array(
      'Basic' => array(
        'realm' => 'api'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Also, it should be noted that Cake no longer supports defining users using the **loginUsers** property. You would probably have to extend the **BasicAuthenticate** class and override it's **getUser()** method.